# Is there any way to print details of data when I click on it?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

On my embedded report which has multiple visuals containing data, I want something like when I click on any data (for ex. a section in pie chart, a row in a table etc.), it should show me things like the visual name, applied filters on it, page name, report id etc.

Is it feasible? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power BI Embedded has Event Handlers to provide data on such events.

You can follow below code snippets to get visual's data when clicked:

1. Get a reference to the HTML element that contains the embedded report:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
```

2. Embed the report:

```js
const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
```

3. Use "dataSelected" event handler to retrieve event details:

```js
report.on("dataSelected", function (event) {
var data = event.detail;
console.log(data);
});
```

The data object will contain the properties of your report and the selected visual.

Please refer:
[How to handle events in a Power BI embedded analytics application | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#dataselected)